# ld: framework not found ,Flutter error on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

I'm trying to build a Flutter App. The app works absolutely fine with Andrioid. But, gives the following error in Xcode build :

```
ld: framework not found
clang error : linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)
```

I have also observed that, although i have my Flutter.framework and App.framework in my Flutter folder. It is not shown in Xcode.

I have tried the following solutions :

1.
cd ios
pod deintegrate
flutter clean
flutter run

2. pod deintegrate and pod install/pod update
3. Changing Run script in Build Phases to
   /bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build

Comment: have you found any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Build Setting and search "Other linker flag".

Delete 2 lines:

"-framework"

""the pub name which is not found""

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).